# Install black[d] from conda

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, python-black

I want to run black as a code formatter in PyCharm. The black website gives specific instructions on how to do so, which is very helpful: https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations/editors.html . However, it uses pip to install `black[d]` while I would like to use conda instead to take advantage of the dependency solver and to have a leaner process.

If I try to simply add `black`, `black[d]`, or `"black[d]"` to the env.yaml file for conda, it installs the simple `black` package without the additional dependencies added by the optional `[d]`. Why is this happening? Is this syntax not accepted by conda or is something missing from the conda-forge repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax is not supported. There are no formal rules for how PyPI packages translate to Conda packages - just have to search and find. For Conda Forge, [the `black-feedstock` builds](https://github.com/conda-forge/black-feedstock/blob/df825dc17e0632d7c548d10d8f25bb7ad1e6f2cf/recipe/meta.yaml#L49) both `black` and `blackd`, which is what you want.

```
mamba install -c conda-forge blackd
```

Comment: Yes, I have already realised that the PyPI -> Conda conversion is sometimes a bit messy — and understandably so, as they all have to prioritise their own way of doing over compatibility with the other platform. Anyways, your answer solved my issue, thank you.